# how to add ngForce to my angular application

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, npm-install

I am trying to integrate sales force with my angular application. After a long search I got [this link](https://github.com/ccoenraets/forceng). As per that I could deploy the static resource to my sales force using grunt deploy using apache ant. Now I want to inject ngForce to my Angular module. But no where I found npm install ngForce like this.
Can some one guide me to integrate sales force to my angular application.

After cloning the repository I added `ngForce` to my module like

```
var app = angular.module('myAwesomeAngularOnSalesforceApp', ['ngForce']);
```

I am getting console error as follows:

```
> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngForce due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngForce.config due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngForce.config' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/nomod?p0=ngForce.config
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2133:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2057:38)
    at module (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2131:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4669:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4653:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4670:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4653:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?
```

i have ngForceConfig.page file like

```
`<apex:page showheader="false" sidebar="false" contenttype="text/javascript">
(function(angular){

    var sitePrefix = '{!$Site.Prefix}';
    if(sitePrefix === '') sitePrefix = '/apex';

    angular.module('ngForce.config', []).constant('ngForceConfig', {
        sessionId: '{!$Api.Session_ID}',
        sitePrefix: sitePrefix,
        resourceUrl: '' <!-- Put the path the static resource here, e.g. '{!URLFOR($Resource.bundle)}' -->
    });

})(angular);
</apex:page>`
```

how i can add this to my index.html.it is not a .js file,it's a page file

Comment: how are you adding the scripts for your modules?

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey i am adding ngForce.js script in index.html as follows
<script src="assets/scripts/ngForce.js"></script>

Comment: should be more specific. The order matters. `myAwesomeAngularOnSalesforceApp` may not have a reference to the `ngForce` module because of it

Comment: @AlekseySolovey after going through there documentation i found that they released a minified script which contain all the dependency of ngForce.i added it in my index.html as follows
<script src="assets/scripts/ngForceWithDependencies.min.js"></script>.after that i got another error ngForce.config' is not available!. In there comment section they are also facing the same issue.last comment in this link
[link](https://github.com/noeticpenguin/ngForce/issues/20).
i also have the ngForceConfig.page in deploy folder.But i dont know how to add it in my index.html.it is not a .js page